# If I add a positive definite matrix, do I increase the norm?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-calculus, positive-definite

I want to show that if $\|A' - B'\|\geq \|A - B\|$ as soon as $A' \succeq A$ and $B' \preceq B$. Is this true?

I could show it if I could show that $\|C + D\| \geq \|C\|$ when $D$ is positive definite.

Comment: What norm are you using?

Comment: The second statement is definitely false, for instance $C=-I$ and $D=\frac{1}{2}I$.

Comment: I guess the condition you'd want is $B'\leq B\leq A \leq A'$. In this case it's true at least for $1 \times 1$ matrices!

Comment: Maybe $\|C+D\|_2\geq \|C\|_2$ is true if $D$ is symmetric, positive definite and $C$ has non-negative entries.

Comment: This is true if we additionally have $A \succeq B$.  In particular, in that case it suffices to note that 
$$
A' - B' = (A' - A) + (A - B) + (B - B')
$$
is a sum of positive semidefinite matrices

Comment: @Omnomnomnom When I add positive deifinite matrices, why is it obvious that the norm increases? I suppose Courant minimax

Comment: @EricAuld That's the quickest way to see it; if $A$ is positive definite, then $\|A\| = \max_{\|x\| = 1}x^*Ax$